# Почему - позвоночник?

Tags: этимология

Попался такой дурацкий заголовок в газете. Но, действительно, какое отношение к звону имеет позвоночник и позвонки?
Спасибо.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Позвоночник не может звенеть, но тем не менее к звону имеет отношение.

Он состоит из позвонков-звеньев, а вот слово "звено", как полагают этимологи, связано со звоном.

"Звено" изначально  - это звенящая часть металлической цепи, а потом просто часть какого-то связанного целого.

Звено - общеславянское слово, но в русском языке известно только с 16 века, и как раз как отрезок большой рыбы от позвонка до позвонка (1547 г.), а 1589 году - это уже кольцо в цепи.

Answer (score 0):

Да просто игра слов. Отсылка к фразе "по ком звонит колокол" используется для привлечения внимания к тексту, только и всего.

Answer (score 0):

Слышала в поликлинике "надоели эти позвоночники". (О пациентах, которых просили принять без очереди по звонку "значительного лица")